# How can I forward port from two multicast addreses with the same port using iptables on debian?

Tags: debian, iptables, port, port-forwarding, multicast

I wrote a multithread program in Python, that analyses traffic from two multicast addresses with the same port, however it looks like my threads don't distinguish from where are datagram's coming.

**Information:**

1st multicast address: `239.0.1.104:12345`
with throughput of 10.69 Mbps

2nd multicast address: `239.0.1.105:12345` with throughput of 6.08 Mbps

The goal of my program is to call analyser two times by two different threads, the desired outcome is that program would print:

`Received 10.69 Mbps!
 Received 6.08 Mbps!`

However currently my program sums up both multicasts and prints:

`Received 16.78 Mbps
 Received 16.78 Mbps`

So I wanted to forward address let's say from 239.0.1.105 to port `12346` instead of `12345` and pass this port into my program hoping that this will help program to distinguish which datagrams are coming to which socket.

How can I do this using iptables?

Also, If this would help, there is the issue of my program asked on programming stack:
[Programming stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57676411/how-can-i-separate-two-sockets-that-receive-two-multicasts-on-the-same-port)

I modified a little bit code to be called by functions, however general idea is the same:

[Current code](https://pastebin.com/yEWT6xFJ)

**ifconfig, my interface and my address**

[image: ifconfig, my interface and my address]

**Route Table**

[image: route table]

**Netstat Output**

[image: netstat]

Comment: Hi, please don't crosspost. As you have one problem with the multicast, I dont see why a iptable rule might help, please find the bug first, and if needed come back after to create the iptables rules

Comment: For your bug I just suspect that .bind(('', MCAST_PORT)) is called, as you define IS_ALL_GROUPS = True

Comment: That was actually true. I had problem with this for 2 weeks...   Could You please explain me what happen in my function `socket_creator`?
As far as I understand: `socket_name = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)` => creating socket with IP proto ver 4, that will receive MC datagrams using UDP.
`socket_name.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` this is responsible for setting parameter that socket could use the same address (and in this case, port, because SO_REUSEADDR = SO_REUSEPORT for Multicasts).

Comment: `if IS_ALL_GROUPS: socket_name.bind(('', MCAST_PORT))` means that if `IS_ALL_GROUPS` is true, bind socket to any addres, and `else: socket_name.bind((MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))` means bind socket to specific given IP address. `mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)` means convert IP address to binary form and
   `socket_name.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)` means that we add membership of group. However I don't understand some thing. Why if I used only one MC_group and set `is_all_groups` to `true` program didnt bound it?

Comment: It was only one addres, and "any" address so in my opinion program should think "okay, this is any addres so I will bind to it". And how does the computer or program distinguish summing up the results? In other words, was the option `is_all_groups=false` setting only one socket that gathered both results, and setting it to true allowed it to open more, or how to understand it?